# HTML5 video player with custom begin end scrubar

Tags: html, html5-video

I need an HTML5 video player implemented using js/angularjs.

Player need custom scrub bar with Three scrubber to indicate

1.Set the Begin of the video to be played
2.Set End of the video to be played
3.Scrubber to move with video time update.

Note: Something like we used in video cutting software, to set begin, an end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some third party libraries? try [Video.JS](http://videojs.com/). you can use it's api to the methods you've asked for. for example:

```
// setting a property on a Video.js player
myPlayer.currentTime(120);
```

add some code so we can help you.